# How does one check if given HTML page will fit on a A4 size page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, dompdf

Given an HTML page source code, i would like to know how to detect whether there is enough space to print the given content.

So far what i do is:

This is my controller:

```
function viewer($mode = NULL){
        $this->load->helper(array('pdf', 'file'));

        $html = $this->load->view('form/document.pdf.php', '',TRUE);
        pdf_create($html, 'ABC_'.time());
}
```

$html is just a plain HTML document, nothing fancy there.

How can i know if the given $html should fit one, two or more A4 pages ?

Comment: You can't.  HTML is a screen-oriented format and not a paper-oriented format.

Comment: Maybe you can by getting the height of the body and with some trial and error.

Comment: @TraianTatic i assume some javascript involved... Anyway i am still looking for the best way to do it.

Comment: Well, saying you can't is somewhat blunt, because you can. A good way to this would be: Create a PDF out of the HTML, like in your example, and see how many pages long it is. PDF's are paper-oriented and will therefore tell you how many pages will be used when it is printed.

Comment: I have just been contemplating the same issue; as a client wants to have headers duplicated where the content is too long for a page. But as the page to PHP is just pure dimension-less html, it is not possible. However best practices would mean that every x amount of rows table headers are repeated, and that images are max-height and width constrained so they don't blow it out.

Comment: @Onyx What i need (and i think the same goes to you) is essentially a text editor like what is being used in Google Docs (http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html), if only they made it opensource....